# ASP.net controls: Browser compatibility

Tags: asp.net

I'm using some ASP.net controls in my project especially WEbcombo,Grid(for inline editing) and i face t working good in firefox and IE6 but not in Safari(throwing exceptions).

so i just wanna know or want a list of ASP.net controls which could not work(if any) in safari(not compatible)

Can u help me in this?

Or do u have anything like which can be included in the ASP code so that i dont have browser compatibility problems (like any code to be included in web.config file OR sumthin )

Do i make sense ?

Comment: That's a pretty abstract question. You might want to narrow it down to 'what control should I use to accomplish 'some task' with cross-browser compatibility'. Or alternatively, does control XYZ work in Safari 3. Etc.

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://swik.net/User:alex/Tips+and+Tricks/Debugging+Javascript+in+Safari/ghpm) is a good link for debugging in the Safari browser. If you are dead set on setting compatibility, you might need this. It focuses more on javascript but people around the campfire say it's good general knowledge. I do not pretend to be an expert in anything Safari, but might be a step in the right direction. Also [this](http://forums.asp.net/t/1252014.aspx) article handles a few more asp .net Safari issues.

Answer (score 0):

ASP.Net is a server side technology.  This means that controls are rendered to HTML by the server before being sent to the browser.  So in most cases, you shouldn't have to worry about what the browser is doing when it comes to ASP.Net controls.  Instead you only have to worry about differences in HTML rendering.

Comment: yes u r correct magnifico.. as u said it depends on HTML rendering..... when u chk out this link http://aspnet.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/050504-1.aspx ,
 u can find things about <browsercaps> .. Can u comment on the use of this tag in web.config? u think it wod work now in safari ??

Comment: This config was used before when ASP.NET treated other browsers (such as Firefox) as down level (sounds utterly stupid, I would think IE was down level..) thus rendering streamlined HTML to them. I don't remember when I last had to use it, a couple of years ago, I guess. It's no longer the case.

Comment: hey i jus used it now... and got error in FIREFOX also (which was working good normally )so now both firefox and Safari are showin errors when i include the <browserCaps> tag...:(

so ultimately i think it's of no use in using the tag.. ?? any comments??

Comment: Server side controls are a convenience.  If you need more control/compatibility you may need to look at a different technology.