# Does ASP.NET MVC provide a more suitable solution to being browser agnostic as opposed to Webforms?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, webforms

Hopefully this question is not to confusing, but I can help clear it up and there *is* a definitive answer: Yes or No (and why of course). I develop a lot of *internal intranet* applications using ASP.NET Webforms targeted for the Windows Environment and IE. This allows things like Windows Authentication and the drag-and-drop ASP.NET server controls work extreamly well and the focus is typically on the function rather than the pazzaz or the look of the site; I'm not selling products here to the masses.

However some users are starting to use Macs, and as we know the default browser is Safari. Unfortunantly Safari does not support Windows Authentication. To add on, a lot of the out-of-the box ASP.NET server controls don't render properly as they do in IE. Plus I have to take into account all the differences I need in my .js as well.

Now looking at this from an internal busniess perspective, having a single enterprise platform is not uncommon, so assuming the users are on IE is not a problem. However as more Macs get introduced, bridging the gap to make these intranet web apps browser agnostic can be quite a difference in development time.

I was wondering if ASP.NET MVC has a leg up on this issue. I know it does not solve the Windows Authentican issue (chime in on this as well for solutions), but I was wondering since server controls were not being used like with web forms, if using MVC was the advantageous choice when trying to make web applications cross browser compatible? I don't mind doing MVC as opposed to webforms, and if there is documented or gained knowledge on why MVC works better for cross browser use, then speak to it. If experience shows the way that MVC renders its controls as opposed to server controls from webforms is better across different browsers, this is mainly what I am trying to detmine.

Does anyone know about this? Thanks!

Comment: That depends on your client-side development skills

Comment: Can you please expand and elaborate a bit?

Comment: Offtopic, but Microsoft should be "shot in the face" for not abandoning web forms.

Comment: Tell that to Scott Guthrie and I think he and a lot of folks at MSFT would disagree, but everyone is entitled to their opinions. Nice to have lots of *different* tools in the toolbox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ASP.NET MVC gives you more *control* about how HTML, CSS, and JavaScript is rendered because you don't have all of the built-in controls that render this for you.  Since you have full control over these elements, you are more enabled for developing in a cross-browser manner.  This puts more burden on developers.  It's a classic power vs. responsibility trade off.

Comment: Would you go for MVC if needing to create a cross-browser intranet application vs webforms *strictly* for the points discussed on this thread? (and not because of better testability, framework, other advantages of MVC etc.)

Comment: No, I wouldn't do it strictly for browser compatibility.

Comment: Thanks. I understand not strictly for that being the only reason, but if this topic came up (amoung many for design) when deciding on which to use, would you choose MVC or Webforms for just any conversations regarding this topic? Or would you say "does not matter?"

Comment: I would choose MVC every time.  It wouldn't be for compatibility.  It would be for better testability, control, and performance.

Answer (score 2):

MVC does do away with the mangled html of server controls, the huge footprint of viewstate, and generally makes the rendered html much cleaner and more efficient. So to answer your question, Yes, MVC will make it easier for you to have clean html that stays just the way you wrote it, without having asp.net's rendering mangle everything.

Answer (score 1):

Windows authentication is supported in Safari. If you are facing issues can you give some specifics.

The web form controls (with newer version of asp.net) usually work across browsers fine. The problem is when it doesn't, it is hard to track them down. I have also had issues where they didn't work well with IE6, tracking them and fixing them is little hard in Web Forms. But that is trade off if you want drag and drop controls.

With MVC, there is no concept of controls similar to web forms. You control everything that is delivered to the client, the HTML, CSS and Javascript files. You do have HTML helpers to render your models to corresponding HTML controls. The amount of extra code you will be writing will depend on the task you are trying to accomplish. Since you control all the assets delivered to the client it makes it easier to track bizarre one off browser specific issues.

Using MVC doesn't mean you won't run into cross browser issues, you will. It may be easier to fix but then if you are experienced in web forms you should be able to achieve the same results.

Comment: Yeah for Safai and Integrate Windows Authentication I looked some more and see this: "Safari works, once you have a Kerberos ticket". With IE everything happens seamlessly without making the user to log onto the site once requesting it. Do you have any information on the (2)?  Also I am an experienced *intranet* web developer but truthfully over the years not had to put a lot of thought into control rendering or extra .js accounting for more than 1 browser. Just typical of an internal enterprise dev I guess.

Comment: If by (2) you mean web forms and cross browser compatibility, it is mostly by experience. For you situation take a look at this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/593605/asp-net-controls-browser-compatibility. If you are comfortable with javascript MVC shouldn't be too much of problem for you.

Comment: Thanks for the follow-up and good info. I actually meant about the 2 - Integrated Windows Authentication and Safari. Do you have any good links on information. I can Google, but I wondered if there was some documentation or blog post that stands out?